# live character count meter error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the code below while I was searching for live character count meter, but it does not work for me. I do not know what is the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#contentbox").keyup(function() {
    var box=$(this).val();
    var count= 300 - box.length;

    if(box.length <= 300) { $("#count").html(count);
    } else {
      var trimmed = $(this).val().substring(0,300);
    $(this).val(trimmed);
    }
  });
});

                <div class="input">
                    <textarea id="contentbox"></textarea>
                    <span class="pull-left"><div id="count">300</div></span>
                    <button class="pull-right">Write</button>
                </div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you looked at the browser console and see if you get any errors? What's the html that goes with that?

Comment: Does seem to be working exactly as expected -> http://jsfiddle.net/H83Aa/ but 300 characters is needed before it does anything ?

Comment: @adeneo in my website, it does not work :/

Comment: @DjOnce - I figured as much, but the above code seems to be working in a seperate test case, so it's not faulty, and if there is nothing wrong with the code you've posted, how are we supposed to help you out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a quick plugin for this a while ago. It might be of some help to you!

http://jsbin.com/urufIc/1/edit?js,output